# Receiver Module Second Data Pin

Tags: wireless

Many of the receiver modules (MX-05V) working with the Virtual Wire library (*I would like to add a link here but it requires 10 reputation, so I'll do that later)* have two data pins. However only one of them is used in the examples I have seen so far.

This picture shows a transmitter (top left) and a receiver (bottom right). Apparently the receiver has four pins - two of them are data pins.

[image: Transmitter and receiver module]

[Image source](http://www.simsso.de/?type=arduino/mx-05v-mx-fs-03v)

**What is the purpose of the second data pin on the receiver module and how to use it?**

Comment: you can still put the part number of the module in your question.  Someone might then edit your post and put in the data sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect only one data line output from the receiver.

Looks like the manufacturer might have just connected the 2 data pins together. You could try using either pin to confirm that the two data output pins are simply connected together.

[image]